# MATLAB figure export is very slow compared to R

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I regularly have to export many figures (hundreds) into a single file. Currently I use

```
  print('-dpsc2', outfile, '-append');
```

My code uses a single hidden figure that is being re-used for each new figure.

Now, the problem is that I can achieve a maximum export speed of around 8 figures per second. In R, you can easily plot around 200 figures per second. Does anyone have any suggestions how to (substantially) speed up MATLAB's exporting capabilities?

Jan

Comment: I suspect that it may be the figure and plot *generation*, rather than the act of *printing* them, that's slow.  At least, it seems that you haven't done the work to isolate the time required to *print* from the time required to *generate* the graphs.  I say that because I can see that you're *not* passing a handle in to your call to print (see, for example, the **handle** argument described at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html ). I bet that if you post the code to generate the graphs, we can help you speed that up quite a bit. Or, you could use the MATLAB Profiler yourself.

Comment: @BobGilmore: No. Just printing the simplest of figures to postscript takes about 0.11 to 0.13 seconds on even a fast computer, whether I pass in a handle to `print` or not.

Comment: Thanks @BobGilmore. Actually, it's really about the export, not about the generation. You can see this if you just export the same figure again and again:
`figure;
plot(rand(10,10));

tic;
for i=1:100
    print('-dpsc2', 'test.ps', '-append');
end;
toc` takes around 10 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel your pain. This issue is also why the `getframe` function for generating movies is so inefficient. The only way I know around it is to write a simpler function that calls the low-level `hardcopy` function. Here's [an example of this for image-based graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56433) along with some caveats. The `hardcopy` function supports both the 'dpsc2' and 'append' options that `print` does:

```
hardcopy(gcf,'outfile.ps','-dpsc2','-append');
```

Whereas `print(gcf,'-dpsc2', 'outfile.ps', '-append');` takes about 0.12 seconds, the above takes only 0.004 seconds on my machine!

If you do `help hardcopy` you won't get very much information. However, if you need to reverse engineer anything you can read the code for `print` (`edit print`) or the various private functions it calls (e.g., `edit private/render`, `edit private/paperfig`, `edit private/ghostscript`).

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing! For my plotting code, I could actually replace my `print` call by a `hardcopy` call and it worked out just fine. Only one particularity: In order to get a white background, I had to call the color changing command as the last graphics command right before the export. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure if this applies to you, but loop unrolling could possibly help you out as well.

Comment: @starbox: Not sure if this is going to work. I profiled `print` and it just spends tons of time in preparing the figure for export. `hardcopy` appears to be a command in the very core of it.

Comment: Be aware that using `hardcopy` with multiple figures open [may slow it down](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/41367-hardcopy-slower-with-more-figures-open). In such cases it even matters the order that you capture the figures in, possibly due to how graphics buffers are handled by your video card (and/or bugs in Matlab).